# Looking for a module similiar to Node's async for Python

Tags: python, node.js, asynchronous

My use case is pretty simple; I have an asynchronous function (calling AWS KMS for decryption) that I need to run multiple times, in parallel. In Node, I would simply use the [async package's](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html) `each` function. However, I'm unfamiliar with how Python handles asynchronicity. Time is short here, so ideally whatever package I used would be easy to setup, and would have a function similar to the above: loop through an array of data and perform a parallel, asynchronous task on each of it's items.

Thanks much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can user python module [asyncio task](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html)